# write and read from excel using powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Any sample to write and read from excel sheet (i need to write values in excel sheet file and read other values after excel execute some its functions) using Powerbuilder "OLE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample of accessing to an Excel file through OLE :

```vb
int li_rtn
string ls_range
oleobject lole_excel, lole_workbook, lole_worksheet, lole_range
lole_excel = create oleobject
li_rtn = lole_excel.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application")
if li_rtn <> 0 then
      MessageBox( "Error", 'Error running MS Excel api.')
      destroy lole_Excel
else
  lole_excel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\some_path_to\sample.xls") 

  lole_workbook = lole_excel.application.workbooks(1)
  lole_worksheet = lole_workbook.worksheets(1)

  // Set the cell value
  lole_worksheet.cells(1,11).value = "Some value" //it is cells(line, column)

  //example to work on a range of cells
  ls_range = "A1:F"+string(ll_excel_rows)
  lole_range = lole_worksheet.Range(ls_range)
  lole_range.Select
  lole_range.Locked = True

  // Save
  lole_workbook.save()
  // Quit
  lole_excel.application.quit()
  lole_excel.DisconnectObject()

  destroy lole_Excel
end if
```

Reading and writing values can be easily done through the `worksheet.cells` property.

The only problem is that driving Excel on a large amount of cells through OLE is slow.

Comment: @M.Ibrahim: sorry, I missed that while refactoring the code from a bigger example. All objects are `oleobject` except the local string used to define an excel range, and the undeclared `ll_excel_rows` that is used as the maximum line number. You can ignore the `.select` and `.locked` lines from the example. I have updated my example