# How to create new empty excel file

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using PowerBuilder 11.5, is there any way i can create new excel worksheet from the powerbuilder code? I am using OLE to write into the existing Excel file, But i want to create a new excel file.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11224462/317266) shows how to access an existing excel document and how to read / write from it.

If you want to create a new document, all you need to do is basically to replace the lines in the example

```
lole_excel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\some_path_to\sample.xls") 
lole_workbook = lole_excel.application.workbooks(1)
```

by

```
lole_workbook = lole_excel.WorkBooks.Add() //this will create the common sheet1/sheet2/sheet3 layout
```

and in the end

```
lole_workbook.save()
```

by

```
lole_workbook.saveAs("C:\some_path_to\a_new_document.xls")
```

Comment: Hi Thank you much, this helped me to solve the issue, thanks again.